# Unable to fetch logs from multiple servers using PsLogList

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am using psloglist to get the eventlogs from remote computers. It works fine for one remote computer but doesn't work for multiple computers.

Works fine:

```
psloglist - \\Server1 -h 4 system -i 7036 -o "Service Control Manager" > c:\temp\logs.txt
```

Doesn't work:

```
psloglist - \\Server1,Server2 -h 4 system -i 7036 -o "Service Control Manager" > c:\temp\logs.txt
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
(for %%a in ( Server1 Server2 ) do (
    psloglist - \\%%a -h 4 system -i 7036 -o "Service Control Manager" 
)) > c:\temp\logs.txt
```

Iterate over the list of servers